# GPUImage crash when switching to background while processing a video file

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am having some problems with `GPUImage` while switching to the background.

In my app I don't capture video using the `GPUImage` classes. The user selects a video from the roll and then my app applies 3 GPUImage filters. The problem comes when the user sends the app to the background when there is still a video processing in progress.

I know I cannot access the GPU while the app is in the background so in my `applicationWillResignActive`: I call to the `GPUImageMovie` and `GPUImageMovieWriter endProcessing` methods. The problem is, even though I call this methods, I still have the `gpus_ReturnNotêrmittedKillClient` error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!